# How can I insert a Google Analytics snippet into my Mediawiki wiki pages?

Tags: google-analytics, mediawiki

This is turning out to be much more challenging than I expected.

There is a Google Analytics Integration extension:

- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Google_Analytics_Integration

But for the Global Site Tag version of Google Analytics, it refers you to the HeadScript extension:

- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:HeadScript

The problem here is the download link (`http://downloads.jingames.net/mediawiki/HeadScript.zip`) looks a bit dodgy and the documentation mentions a bug.

I've also reviewed this discussion on the Mediawiki site:

- [How can I add the code into the `<head>`?](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Unn6ubkgl5ppj467)

But it's a lot of telling and not much showing.

The Google Analytics snippet looks like this:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=TRACKING_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'TRACKING_ID');
</script>
```

I would prefer to insert it by updating a setting in `LocalSettings.php` config file.

Answer (score 8):

I found a way to insert the tag into `LocalSettings.php` using the `$wgHooks` setting as demonstrated here:

- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Uxv32na6lh6wd5rf

Just replace `TRACKING_ID` (in both spots) with your Analytics tracking ID and paste this at the bottom of `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgHooks['BeforePageDisplay'][] = function( OutputPage &$out, Skin &$skin ) {
     $code = <<<HTML
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=TRACKING_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'TRACKING_ID');
</script>
HTML;

     $out->addHeadItem( 'gtag-insert', $code );
     return true;
};
```

Comment: adding it to MediaWiki:Common.js is an alternative, all users will have it run regardless of which skin  is installed

Comment: @Mousey That's a good idea, but how exactly do you implement it? I tried pasting the whole tracking code and it didn't work. I figured what is in common.js should only be js codes, so I removed the `<script>` tag... but where will I put the `<script>` for the googletagmanager url? Maybe a js code on adding urls? Perhaps there's a way on the LocalSettings to add script urls? Just thinking maybe you already have the solution. Also, does adding things in the LocalSettings.php changes when you change skin?

Comment: Can confirm that this also works with the new 'Analytics 4' from Google. The code from Tom is pretty much a drop-in solution.

Comment: `MediaWiki:Common.js` does not run on mobile devices when MobileFrontent is enabled. You'll need to add the code to `MediaWiki:Mobile.js` as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old post but for anyone else who might happen upon this I have found a possible solution by combining other examples.

I have used [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9381758/tom-at-ffi)'s code as an example and replace the corresponding variables within the [google analytics extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Google_Analytics_Integration).

1. Change the hook in googleAnalytics.hooks.php line 9.

Old:

```php
...
public static function onSkinAfterBottomScripts( Skin $skin, &$text = '' ) {
...
```

New:

```php
...
public static function onBeforePageDisplay( OutputPage &$out, Skin $skin ) {
...
```

2. Then replace all mentions of `$text` with `$code`, there are 5 of them on lines, 14, 24, 31, 54, and 59.
3. Then at the end of the parser function above the `return true;` insert the following code on line 61.

```php
$out->addHeadItem( 'gtag-insert', $code );
```

4. Finally go into googleAnalytics.php line 52 (Bottom of file) and replace the hook call to use the new hook.

Old:

```php
...
$wgHooks['SkinAfterBottomScripts'][] = 'GoogleAnalyticsHooks::onSkinAfterBottomScripts';
...
```

New:

```php
...
$wgHooks['BeforePageDisplay'][] = 'GoogleAnalyticsHooks::onBeforePageDisplay';
...
```

If everything worked out you will see the [googleAnalytics extension script in the head element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPVCy.png) as opposed to [within the body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7BvQ.png). I am going to try and contact the creator/contributors of the extension and see if it can be change or ask why its not this way already.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [google analytics extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Google_Analytics_Integration).
Alternatively, the script can be added to Mediawiki:Common.js using `document.write` to link to the url and your site's UA-xxxxxx-x:

`// GOOGLE ANALYTICS (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'); ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-x', 'auto'); ga('send', 'pageview');`

`// END GOOGLE ANALYTICS`

Comment: Note that the Google Analytics extension has not been updated since 2017.